# nth-child selector not working in sass

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to get an animation to effect a box a different timed intervals to make a domino effect.

Here is my code

```
    #portfolioContent {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;

    h1 {
        @include header;    
    }

    .portfolioBox {
        height:350px;
        width:300px;
        position:relative;
        margin:15px 10px 30px 10px;
        float:left;
        border-radius:10px;
        position:relative;
        animation: swing 1s ease-in-out 1,
        fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 1;

            img {
                border-radius:10px;
            }

            &:hover #portfolioBoxRollOver {
                border:30px solid map-get($colorMap, bannerColor);
                opacity:.8;
            }

            &:hover #portfolioTitle {

                color:map-get($colorMap, bannerColor);
            }
        }

        #portfolioBoxRollOver {
            position:absolute;
            height:300px;
            width:100%; 
            border:0px solid black;
            opacity:0;
            border-radius:10px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
            transition:all .1s ease-in-out;
            }

        #portfolioTitle {
            position:absolute;
            height:50px;
            text-align:center;
            background-color:#CCC;
            bottom:0px;
            width:100%;
            line-height:50px;
            border-radius:0px 0px 10px 10px;
            color:map-get($colorMap, headerColor);
            }
}
```

for some reason .portfolioBox:nth-child(1) {animation-delay:2s;} selects every portfolio box instead of just the first one. What am I doing wrong?

I even tried nesting in .portfolioBox in sass using `&:nth-child(1) {animation-delay:2s;}`

Here is the html as requested>>

```
<div id="mainContent">
        <div id="portfolioContent">
        <h1>Portfolio</h1>
            <a href="#">
            <div class="portfolioBox">
            <div id="portfolioBoxRollOver"></div><!-- end of portfolioBoxRollOver-->
                <img src="images/bindy_site.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt=""/>
            <div id="portfolioTitle">
        <h2>Bindy's Bicycle</h2>
              </div><!-- end of portfolioTitle-->
           </div><!-- end of portfolioBox--> </a>
            <a href="#">
            <div class="portfolioBox">
             <div id="portfolioBoxRollOver"></div><!-- end of portfolioBoxRollOver-->
            <img src="images/sellwood_podiatry_site.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt=""/>
            <div id="portfolioTitle">
        <h2>Sellwood Podiatry</h2>
              </div><!-- end of portfolioTitle-->
            </div><!-- end of portfolioBox--></a>
            <a href="#">
            <div class="portfolioBox">
             <div id="portfolioBoxRollOver"></div><!-- end of portfolioBoxRollOver-->
                <img src="images/st_cecilia_site.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt=""/>
            <div id="portfolioTitle">
        <h2>St. Cecilia Website</h2>
              </div><!-- end of portfolioTitle-->
         </div><!-- end of portfolioBox--></a> 
            <a href="#">
            <div class="portfolioBox">
             <div id="portfolioBoxRollOver"></div><!-- end of portfolioBoxRollOver-->
                <img src="images/sennheiser_website.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt=""/>
                <div id="portfolioTitle">
        <h2>Sennheiser Website</h2>
                </div><!-- end of portfolioTitle-->
           </div><!-- end of portfolioBox--></a>
            <a href="#">
            <div class="portfolioBox">
             <div id="portfolioBoxRollOver"></div><!-- end of portfolioBoxRollOver-->
                <img src="images/portland_chess_club_site.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt=""/>
                <div id="portfolioTitle">
        <h2>Portland Chess Club</h2>
                </div><!-- end of portfolioTitle-->
            </div><!-- end of portfolioBox--></a>
            <a href="#">
            <div class="portfolioBox">
             <div id="portfolioBoxRollOver"></div><!-- end of portfolioBoxRollOver-->
                <img src="images/bud_tenders_site.jpg" width="300" height="300" alt=""/>
                <div id="portfolioTitle">
        <h2>Bud Tenders</h2>
                </div><!-- end of portfolioTitle-->
            </div><!-- end of portfolioBox--></a>
        </div><!-- end of portfolioContent-->
    </div><!-- end of mainContent-->
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet for your code

Answer (score 3):

> For some reason .portfolioBox:nth-child(1) {animation-delay:2s;} selects every portfolio box instead of just the first one. What am I doing wrong?

You think that `.portfolioBox:nth-child(1)` selects the first every appearing element with class `.portfolioBox`. The thing with `nth-child` is that it selects every matching element that is the nth-child of its parent.

```
<div id="parent">
  <p class="someChild">Content1</p> <!-- this is always the first child -->
  <div class="portfolioBox">Content2</div>  <!-- this is always the second child -->
</div>
<!-- so .portfolioBox:nth-child(1) won't match here, as the first child is not -->
<!-- of class .portfolioBox -->
```

In your example you have the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="portfolioContent">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="portfolioBox">...</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="portfolioBox">...</div>
  </a>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

So by saying `.portfolioBox:nth-child(1)` you select every element of class `.portfolioBox` that is the first child of its parent. In your example that's the case for every `.portfolioBox` element (`<a>` is the parent).

#### Solution

Assuming that the first `.portfolioBox` is always in the first `<a>` tag of its parent, we could try to select the first `<a>` element and style its `.portfolioBox`:

```
#portfolioContent > a:nth-child(2) > .portfolioBox {
  background: yellow;
}
```

This is not yet perfect as we have to care about the position of the first `<a>` element. Currently it's the second child of `#portfolioContent`, the first one is `<h1>`. Fortunately, there is the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)-selector which allows to select the first child of type `<a>`:

```
#portfolioContent > a:nth-of-type(1) > .portfolioBox {
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.portfolioBox {
    height:350px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    margin:15px 10px 30px 10px;
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:relative;
    animation: swing 1s ease-in-out 1,
    fadeIn 1s ease-in-out 1;
    &:first-child{
      /*Code Here*/
    }
 }
```

Also use &:nth-child(n) for selecting other elements.

Comment: it still selects all the .portfolioBox using that method. Even though it seems most logical.

Comment: Oh.. Based on your current html structure we cant get the nth element. give 'portfolioBox ' class to <a> tag. it will work.

Comment: Is that fixed ?

Comment: Is the issue fixed?

Comment: No mitivation.. I am just tried to help you. is that fixed?

Answer (score 0):

.portfolioBox:nth-child(1)  is actually selecting the 1st child of .portfolioBox, which in your case doesn't exist, so it must be defaulting to select .portfolioBox instead. You could always just use

```
h1 .portfolioBox
```

as the selector rule. It depends exactly what you're trying to achieve.

If you want to always select the 1st instance of your .portfolioBox class, then you need to style all instances of .portfolio, then apply a different styling to all instances except the 1st one, like this:

Apply to all elements using .portfolioBox:

```
.portfolioBox { styles }
```

Now apply different styles to 'undo' this styling, for all siblings of the 1st instance of .portfolioBox:

```
.portfolioBox ~ .portfolioBox { styles }
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Your explanation and proposed solution are not correct. `.portfolioBox:nth-child(1)` selects every element of class .portfolioBox that is the first child of its parent. It *does* exist in his case, that's why every portfolioBox gets selected as stated in the question. Then I would like to add that the sibling selector won't work this way, because the portfolioBoxes have different parents. In general your idea is fine, but you have to change it to a selection of the siblings of the `<a>` tag.